# bash $FUNCNAME array not being cleared

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, function, debugging

I have quite a few functions that are often nested in each other. For simple debugging purposes, I decided to use `FUNCNAME` environment variable array provided by `bash` to trace the code flow. Here is the example code:

```
test1(){ test2;}
test2(){ test3;}
test3(){ test4;}
test4(){ echo ${FUNCNAME[@]};}
```

And the output looks like this:

```
test4 test3 test2 test1
```

Which quite clearly shows the nesting, but if you terminate the function with `ctr+c`, and run it again, `FUNCNAME` is not flushed, so the output might look like this (depending on when did you terminate it):

```
test4 test3 test2 test1 test3 test2 test1
```

I tried to clear or `unset` `FUNCNAME` manually, but then I get empty output. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I tried on Debian Stable (bash  4.3.30) and I cannot reproduce that problem.  Can you provide more details: What OS and bash version are you using?  How did you time your ctrl-C?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release-(i686-pc-cygwin), put `sleep 2` in each function, run `test1`, terminate it after a couple of seconds, run `test1` again, output will contain a part of the old "chain" at the end.

Comment: Are you running you sourcing your script in the current shell (i.e. running it with a dot-forward-slash)like this: `./script`? If so, you will be continually updating the FUNCNAME variable...

Comment: I can reproduce; I'd say this is likely a bug. (I only source the file once, to define the four functions; calling `test1` once with interruption and again to completion shows that `FUNCNAME` accumulates.)

Comment: It's not clear how you would fix this, though. You don't want to clear it after the signal interrupts the call, since you might want to examine the value after the premature interruption, which leaves you with resetting the value when you call the next function. But how do you determine which function calls are "root" calls that should clear the value? (Although I'm probably just too unfamiliar with `bash` internals to see the right way to do this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some could say that this issue is a feature, not a bug. If any of the functions in the stack crash, you can `echo ${funcname[@]}` to see where did the crash occur. The final verdict is: the issue was reported as a bug, and is fixed in `bash` v4.4.0.